# What is the meaning of the expression used by Dorothy?

Tags: plot-explanation, blue-velvet

In Blue Velvet (1986) Dorothy says these words to Jeffrey Beaumon after making love to him:

> I have your disease in me now.

I am thinking disease means related to STD. Am I thinking correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's meant to be intentionally ambiguous. The Director, David Lynch, left it undefined so that people could relate to it more. It means what you want it to mean. It does not specifically mean an STI. It could mean love.

> Regarding the sentence "He put his disease in me." in Blue Velvet:
>
> "Just the word **disease** used in that way – it's so beautiful just to leave it abstract. Once it becomes specific it's no longer true to a lot of people. Where if it's abstract there could be some truth to it for everybody."
> <sub>-"Lynch on Lynch", the ticket into the world of David Lynch edited by Chris Rodley.</sub>

Answer (score -2):

After searching around for answers to this, I'm surprised that more people aren't curious what it means. We all know basically what it refers to on a literal level but why does she call it a disease? What does that mean? Simply brainstorming possibilities here, this could refer to:

Love 
Hope 
Masculinity 
Any genetic tendency he has toward voyeurism/perversion, as she understands it 
Life (I think there's an anti-natalist strand in several of Lynch's works)

She dared to love and create new life before and this brought her suffering and imprisonment. It's not surprising that she would associate men/sex with suffering. Not only in regards to the conception of her son but also the um peculiar way that Frank relates to her sexually on an ongoing basis.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).